# When does OAuth re-authenticate users?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I assume OAuth protocol being something like this:

- user registers to Gitlab using Facebook (for example)
- Facebook asks if user accepts sharing profile info with Gitlab
- user accepts
- Gitlab receives user profile
- user asks Gitlab for a private resource
- **?? HOW GITLAB KNOWS IT STILL CAN TRUST THE USER ??**
- Gitlab sends private resource to user

At first I assumed that Gitlab might just check if the user is logged through Facebook: if yes, then it's him. However, if I login to Gitlab using Facebook, but then decide to logout from Facbook... I still can operate on Gitlab.

So I guess there is another workflow to RE-authenticate the user even if facebook is logged off, but I can't seem to find how ?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is a delegation protocol that helps with authorization decisions ([source](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)). In fact, it doesn't really provide authentication, and it likely doesn't know or care whether you are still authenticated or not at the identity provider (Facebook).

If you look into how OAuth works, all that really happens is that an access token is generated by the identity provider, and is given to the client website (GitLab). This token will have authorization to access the Facebook Graph API on your behalf. Once GitLab has pulled the necessary information from the API, it doesn't really need to access it anymore. Thus, GitLab doesn't keep checking whether or not you are still logged into Facebook. The token itself is probably still valid as well until it expires.

TL;DR: Facebook Connect (which uses OAuth) grants GitLab access to query information about the user from Facebook. GitLab uses this to identify the user and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer. What I don't really get with the workflow you describe is that if I go to my Facebook settings and revoke the Gitlab app access, Gitlab does NOT disconnect instantly but will at the next operation I do... So I believe Gitlab does ask facebook's authorization before every private action. Right? So, if that is, I don't get why people trust OAuth: authorization is delegated to a trusted 3rd party, however USER IDENTITY IS NEVER VERIFIED AGAIN !

Comment: @JonaRodrigues I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "next operation" or "private action", but this is really implementation specific to whatever application is being used and I do not think it is part of any standard. You are correct that OAuth should not be used for authentication/identity (although Facebook Connect isn't just OAuth), I believe the link in my answer explains it. If not, there are some blog posts on the subject.